# How to use Pandas to block average data frame with a length of 10 frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am new to Pandas. So I wonder whether there are some ways better to finish this task.

I have a data frame like the following format:

[image: Data for DNA geometry parameters]

This is a DNA simulation data from molecular dynamics.

And the data set is here:[BPdata.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzspsqjo9itfmbp/BPdata.csv?dl=0)

So, here is in total 1000 Frames and my purpose is to get the average of each 10 Frames, So, in the end, I want the data to be like this:

```
Block  Base1 Base2 Shear Stretch Stagger .....
 1     1      66     XX    XX     XX
 1     2      65     XX    XX     XX
...   ...     ...    ...   ...    ...
 1     33     34     XX    XX     XX

 2     1      66     XX    XX     XX
 2     2      65     XX    XX     XX
...   ...     ...    ...   ...    ...
 2     33     34     XX    XX     XX

 3     1      66     XX    XX     XX
 3     2      65     XX    XX     XX
...   ...     ...    ...   ...    ...
 3     33     34     XX    XX     XX


 4     1      66     XX    XX     XX
 4     2      65     XX    XX     XX
...   ...     ...    ...   ...    ...
 4     33     34     XX    XX     XX
```

Where Block 1 represents the mean of 1 ~ 10 Frames and 2 represents Frame 11 ~ 20.

Although, I think by carefully assign the index of each row I can finish these task, I wonder whether there is some convenient way to finish this task. I have checked some web pages about the `groupby`  functions in `pandas` by it seems does not have this group each 10 row to get a block average function.

Thank you!

**=============================== Update ==================================**

Sorry for not be clear on the description of my purpose, and I have figured out a way to do the task and a sample output to better illustrated my purpose.

For double strand DNA, We know it is a double helix structure with AGCT, so Base1 means one base for DNA and Base2 means the complementary base of another strand. The two corresponding bases are linked together by hydrogen bonds.

like:

```
Base1 : AAAGGGCCCTTT
        ||||||||||||
Base2 : TTTCCCGGGAAA
```

So here in `BPdata.csv` each combination of Base1 and Base2 means a pair of DNA bases.

Here in `BPdata.csv`, this is a 33 base pair DNA simulated in different time frames noted as 1,2,3,4...1000.

Then I want to group each 10-time frames together, like 1~10,11~20,21~30...., and in each group, do the average for each Base pair.

And here is the data I figured out:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import pandas as pd

    '''

    Data Input

    '''


    # Import CSV data to Python


    BPdata = pd.read_csv("BPdata.csv", delim_whitespace = True, skip_blank_lines = False)
    BPdata.rename(columns={'#Frame':'Frame'}, inplace=True)

    '''

    Data Processing

    '''
    # constant block average parameters
    Interval20ns = 10
    IntervalInBPdata = 34


    # BPdataBlockAverageSummary
    LEN_BPdata = len(BPdata)

    # For Frame 1
    i = 1
    indexStarting = 0
    indexEnding =  0  

    indexStarting = indexEnding
    indexEnding =  Interval20ns * IntervalInBPdata * i - 1

    GPtemp = BPdata.loc[indexStarting : indexEnding]
    GPtemp['Frame'] = str(i)
    BPdata_blockOF1K_mean = GPtemp.groupby(['Frame','Base1','Base2']).mean()
    BPdata_blockOF1K_mean.loc[len(BPdata_blockOF1K_mean)] = str(i)
    # For Frame 2 and so on
    i = i + 1
    indexStarting = indexEnding + 1
    indexEnding =  Interval20ns * IntervalInBPdata * i - 1
    while ( indexEnding <= LEN_BPdata - 1):
        GPtemp = BPdata.loc[indexStarting : indexEnding]
        GPtemp['Frame'] = str(i)
        meanTemp = GPtemp.groupby(['Frame','Base1','Base2']).mean()
        meanTemp.loc[len(meanTemp)] = str(i)    
        BPdata_blockOF1K_mean = pd.concat([BPdata_blockOF1K_mean,meanTemp])
        i = i + 1
        indexStarting = indexEnding + 1
        indexEnding =  Interval20ns * IntervalInBPdata * i - 1
```

And the result is something like this, which is what I wanted:

[image: Results]

And here is the sample output, [BPdataresult.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvs2y0h5pcyfvtb/BPdataresult.csv?dl=0)

But so far I got there warnings:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   GPtemp['Frame'] = str(i) /home/iphyer/Downloads/dataProcessing.py:62:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   GPtemp['Frame'] = str(i)

And Here I wonder:

1. Is this warning serious?
2. Due `groupby` function of `Pandas`, now the index of the data frame is a combination of `(Frame,Base1,Base2)`, how can I separate them apart like the original form. Instead supplement `#Frame` to `Block` index.
3. Can I improve the code OR use some more Pandas way to do this task?

Best!

Comment: Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, you can do: `df.groupby(df['#Frame']//10).mean()`. Also, you should probably rename the column `#Frame` to just `Frame`.

Comment: @Abdou , Thx, I have updated the descriptions. And there are some new problems now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping in pandas can be done in a variety of ways. One of those ways is to pass a series. So you could pass a series that has values for 10 row blocks. The solutions works as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create datafram with 1000 rows
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000, 1)

#create series for grouping
groups_of_ten = pd.Series(np.repeat(range(int(len(df)/10)), 10))

#group the data
grouped = df.groupby(groups_of_ten)

#aggregate
grouped.agg('mean')
```

The grouping series looks like this on the inside:

```
In [21]: groups_of_ten.head(20)
Out[21]:
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    1
11    1
12    1
13    1
14    1
15    1
16    1
17    1
18    1
19    1
```

Comment: Hi, @Woody Pride, I have tried your solution, but the results look like this: `       #Frame      Base1      Base2     Shear   Stretch   Stagger    Buckle  \
0   485.803153  16.995941  50.004059  0.017325 -0.042114  0.067136  1.731197  
` But I want to maintain the original structure of the first frame.

Comment: For example, I want to maintain not only the mean but also each mean of the Base1 Base2 records.

Comment: Im afraid I do not understand your problem. If you would care to update your questions with a small reproducible example and expected output then perhaps someone will post a more complete solution.